# submit the multiple forms on same button click using ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

i want to know that how can i submit two or more form on same button click and in single requests, actually i m uploading an image and using enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: why not just use javascript to collect the data from the two forms, merge them, and then post via ajax?  using libraries like dojo or jquery makes this easy, but it can be done with basic javascript.  note, it will help to have different form field names for the two forms to avoid conflicts in the merge.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need AJAX for that, only javascript. Just make sure the submit won't reload the page while you're at it, i.e. set target to some hidden iframe.

```
form1.target = "_hiddenFrame";
form1.submit();
form2.target = "_hiddenFrame";
form2.submit();
```

If you insist on AJAX (not a bad thing) you need to collect data from all these forms, build a proper request and submit it.

Comment: Note that this will submit the form in two separate requests.

Comment: well, he never said the action attribute for both forms match

Comment: actually, i want to submit the form on same request i was searching and reading about Ajax and then i thought that it might be possible because of Ajax as it asynchronously send request to the server

Comment: I know, I'm just pointing it out.
@john you cannot submit two forms on the same request.  With javascript you could assemble a request containing the fields of both forms and submit.  Is this the kind of thing you're after?  It might be easier to just try to get all the fields into one form.  Anyway, some more details about what you're trying to achieve would be helpful.